# Set the base url of any menu item in Joomla

Tags: url, plugin, joomla

I'm not sure if this belongs here, superuser or stackoverflow

I'm using virtual domains, which means that www.company.com has one template www.community.com has another template user accounts are shared

the site is also in 2 languages

now there is a common global Menu navigation and some links should be on the company.com url and some on the community.com url. however menu links stay on the current domain I'm on for example: 1. i'm on company.com/de/about 2. click on forum link 3. want to land on community.com/de/forum

however I land on company.com/de/forum but i don't want to use "external links" because if I am on community.com/en/forum and click on about link i need the url to be company.com/en/about so the urls still need to be dynamic for language support.

In other words I want to be able to set the base url of any menu item no matter what component, where should I start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the component [ReReplacer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/rereplacer). It will allow you to replace certain urls to their full urls. In this case you could ensure that all * /en/ * point to one domain while all * /de/ * point to the other. It's not the most ideal solution but it has helped me out where I use a SSL certificate for specific pages only (not menus) where otherwise I would have had no solution.